# I have a fatal error on my WPforms LITE plug in, my forms aren't arriven

Tags: wordpress, plugins, fatal-error, elementor, wpforms

A while ago I had a problem with the Forms I was using to capture my leads information, someone told me to "disabling the cache plugin", but Google kept registering conversions that arent arriven to my e-mail.

Today I recived an e-mail from Worpress telling me that my plug in had a fatal error on WPForms:

"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function monsterinsights_get_ua() in /home/u796248309/domains/metametalicos.com.br/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpforms-lite/src/Admin/Pages/Analytics.php:443 Stack trace: #0 /home/u796248309/domains/metametalicos.com.br/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpforms-lite/src/Admin/Pages/Analytics.php(321): WPForms\Admin\Pages\Analytics->get_data_step_setup() #1 /home/u796248309/domains/metametalicos.com.br/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpforms-lite/src/Admin/Pages/Analytics.php(191): WPForms\Admin\Pages\Analytics->output_section_step_setup() #2 /home/u796248309/domains/metametalicos.com.br/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): WPForms\Admin\Pages\Analytics->output() #3 /home/u796248309/domains/metametalicos.com.br/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters() #4 /home/u796248309/domains/metametalicos.com.br/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action() #5 /home/u796248309/domains/metametalicos.com.br/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpforms-lite/includes/admin/class-menu.php(326): do_action() #6 /home/u796248309/domains/metametalicos.com.br/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): WPForms_Admin_Menu->admin_page() #7 /home/u796248309/domains/metametalicos.com.br/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters() #8 /home/u796248309/domains/metametalicos.com.br/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action() #9 /home/u796248309/domains/metametalicos.com.br/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(259): do_action() #10 {main} thrown in /home/u796248309/domains/metametalicos.com.br/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpforms-lite/src/Admin/Pages/Analytics.php on line 443
There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions."

I Try to talk to my hosting support but they coudn't help, and can't get in touch with WPForms.